# Swift: delete all array elements

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to delete all array elements with a for loop like this:

```
for index 1...myArray.count {
   myArray.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

But it doesn't work, I get this error before bulding:

> Expected ';' in 'for' statement

Comment: Simple. re-initialize the array...

Answer (score 407, accepted):

There is a method (actually a function)

```
myArray.removeAll()
```

Comment: better to call it a `function` ;)

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan why `function` and not `method`? Because of the keyword `func`?

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath Strictly spoken Swift arrays are `struct`s and structs have `functions` unlike classes which have `methods`.

Comment: @vadian +1 for the clarification. I forgot `Array`s are `struct`s. Veteran Objective-C coder here...

Comment: do you need to call the removeAll() function when exiting a view (viewcontroller) where you initialize it, or does it go away on its own!?

Comment: @FamicTech It depends: If the view is unloaded it goes away implicitly, if the view only disappears you have to call `removeAll()`. However it's good (memory discipline) practice to remove all unnecessary data when a view disappears.

Comment: Which is better, `myArray.removeAll()` or `myArray = []`?

Answer (score 22):

Taking for granted that @vadian's answer **is the solution**, I would just want to point out that your code doesn't work.

First of all, array indexes are 0-based, so you should rewrite the range accordingly:

```
for index 0..<myArray.count {
   myArray.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

However this implementation is going to cause a crash. If you have an array of 10 elements, the last element occupies the position at index 9.

Using that loop, at the first iteration the element at index 0 is removed, and that causes the last element to shift down at index 8.

At the next iteration, the element at index 1 is removed, and the last element shifts down at index 7. And so on.

At some point in the loop, an attempt to remove an element for a non existing index will cause the app to crash.

When removing elements from an array in a loop, the best way of doing it is by traversing it in reverse order:

```
for index in reverse(0..<myArray.count) {
    myArray.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

That ensures that removed elements don't change the order or the index of the elements still to be processed.

Comment: There is a function to remove all the elements in just single line. as @vadian's answer...

Comment: @V.J. that's what I wrote in the first line of my answer :)

Comment: +1 for a solution that can be used to remove a particular instance of an object. I use `public extension Array where Element : Equatable { public mutating func remove(element: Element) -> Int { var occurrences = 0; for index in (0 ..< count).reverse() { if self[index] == element { removeAtIndex(index); occurrences += 1 } }; return occurrences } }` preferably not all one line but that code should compile on one line

Comment: Why not `for _ in 0...<myArray.count { myArray.removeAtIndex(0) }`? I don't know very much about efficiency yet, but this way you don't need to reverse the range, so maybe it's faster.

Comment: That works too! Same method in terms of efficiency, you remove from the beginning instead of the end, but you save a variable :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to clear the array, the simplest way is to Re-Initialize it.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the `in` keyword which is causing your error. The code should be:

```
for index in 1...myArray.count {
    myArray.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

**This will however not work as you would expect for a couple of reasons:**

- The last valid index is `count - 1` which would require `1..<myArray.count`
- More importantly removing an element from an array shortens it thus changing the indexes each time.

If you're trying to remove all things from the array then you should do as others have suggested and use:

```
myArray.removeAll()
```

In the case that you do only want the first element and nothing else you could get a reference to the first object, empty the array, then add the object back on:

```
var firstElement = myArray.first!
myArray.removeAll()
myArray.append(firstElement)
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't seen "in"... Did +1

Comment: (+1) for explaining the actual error. (-1) because this will not work, as deleting an item makes the array shorter . (Note also that the *last* valid index is `count - 1`).

Answer (score 5):

Your code should work, it is just out of bound.

**Swift 3**

```
existingArray = []
```

By doing this you re-assign an empty array to the existing array and the data type is referred.

Alternatively, you can use `removeAll` which removes all elements from the array and provide an option to keep the existing capacity.

```
existingArray.removeAll()
```

This is a `mutating` function which means the array calling the method will be changed (empty).

Answer (score 2):

Kyle is on the right track, but his code will fail as the possible indices reduces during enumerating, leading to illegal indices.

One way to solve it is to enumerate backwards. In swift this is done by using *strides*.

```
for index in stride(from: myArray.count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
    myArray.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

another options would be to use `filter()`

Swift 1.2

```
myArray = filter(myArray, { (obj) -> Bool in
    return false
})
```

Swift 2

```
myArray = myArray.filter{ (obj) -> Bool in
    return false
}
```

Comment: Very interesting! I didn't know about `stride`

Answer (score 2):

There is **removeAllObjects()** method available in Swift 2

```
Syntax :  public func removeAllObjects()
Eg.:   mainArray.removeAllObjects
```

To remove element at particular index use :

```
Syntax : public func removeObjectAtIndex(index: Int)
Eg.: mainArray.removeObjectAtIndex(5)
```

To remove last element use :

```
Syntax : public func removeLastObject()
Eg.: mainArray.removeLastObject()
```

To remove elements in particular range use :

```
Syntax : public func removeObject(anObject: AnyObject, inRange range: NSRange)
```

To remove particular element use :

```
Syntax : public func removeObject(anObject: AnyObject)
```

Below screenshot shows list of method available in NSMutableArray extension

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
for _ in myArray
{
    myArray.removeAtIndex(0)
}
```

Comment: This solution is awfully inefficient - on each iteration all subsequent objects index are shifted. Also, I'm not sure is this implementation safe. At least in Objective-C collections mutation during enumeration is prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

Vadian has the correct answer in terms of what you're trying to accomplish. The issue shown as a result of your code sample is due to the way you're trying to create the `for` loop. `Index` will start at 0 by default. Adding in a number range after it is not the correct way to create a for loop. That's why you're seeing the error. Instead, create your for loop as follows:

```
for index in myArray.indices {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Hopefully, this answer will help others that are new to Swift or programming.

Comment: you should use the array indices property to when iterating the collection. Not all collections starts at zero index